# Добавить к таблице БД столбцы или простейшая реализация EAV

Tags: база-данных, хранение-данных

Есть таблица товаров `Product`.

```
+------------------+
| Product          |
+------------------+
| id_product  [PK] |
| id_company  [FK] |
| name             |
| art              |
| cost             |
+------------------+
```

Каждый товар относится к какой либо компании. Но помимо 3х обязательных полей компания может добавить дополнительные столбцы на свое усмотрение.

Как это можно реализовать?

Растягивать таблицу новыми столбцами, полагаю будет не верным решением.
Или же можно добавить две таблицы `Custom-cell` - названия доп. столбцов и `CC-Product` - связь доп. столбцов с товарами. Но думаю плохое решение.

```
+-------------+
| Custom-cell |
+-------------+
| id_cs  [PK] |
| name        |
| type        |
+-------------+

+------------------------+
| CC-Product             |
+------------------------+
| id_cc      |      [FK] |
| id_product |[PK]  [FK] |
| value                  |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Вам нужен EAV в дополнении к вашей имеющейся структуре

Comment: @ArchDemon Отлично, теперь есть от чего оттолкнуться

Comment: @ArchDemon по сути второй вариант и является EAV моделью?

Comment: Ну если в общем случае, то да. Это он и есть. E - это ваша первая таблица, А - вторая и V - третья.